# How to create byte array and fill it with random data

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a byte array against the given size filled with random data.How can I do that?Signature of my method would be like this:

```
private byte[]  GetByteArray(int sizeInKb)
    {


    }
```

This is what I have tried:

```
private  byte[]  GetByteArray(int sizeInKb)
    {

        var rnd = new Random();
        var bytes = new Byte[sizeInKb*1024];
        rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Here I want to return byte array conataining random data against value of sizeInKb. Is my array size correct , when user inputs value in kb e.g. 10 KB.

Comment: How random do they need to be? Have you looked at [Random.NextBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: Also, do you need pseudo random or cryptographically secure (pseudo) random numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill byte array with junk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985188/how-to-fill-byte-array-with-junk) (where "random data" is indistinguishable from "junk").  There are many other [near duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+c%23+fill+array+random), though they either specify the random numbers be unique and/or within a certain range.

Comment: @Chris: I just edited my question . Its arraysize .

Comment: Your code looks fine. What makes you think this might not be working?

Comment: @Chris: the conversion factor from KB , I was not sure .Thanks for letting know.

Comment: Well depending on context some people might think it should be `*1024` and some `*1000`. Only you can say which is actually correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819763/really-1-kb-kilobyte-equals-1024-bytes for some discussion on this.

Comment: I'm confused how/why this question was framed as being about creating an array with random numbers, when the real information that was desired was edited in afterwards, which is essentially "How do I calculate the number of bytes in a KB"?  Why not just ask that in the first place?  And how does the accepted answer...answer that question?

Comment: @BACON accepted answer + comments below the accepted answer completes the whole picture

Comment: @Kumar your edit of the question made answer completely unrelated to the question (making it really not an answer as it simply copy-pastes the code from the question). You really should not be doing so...

Comment: just to be clear, @Kumar copied and pasted the code from my answer, then asked a second question

Comment: I wrote up an equivalent example that calls `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(byte[])`  instead, but as I reached for the "Post Your Answer" button, the question closed.  It's basically the same code, but with a call to GetBytes wrapping in a `using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())` block

Comment: @panohh: Nope I did not copy from your answer, I have edited earlier than you posted with correct size of array and I noticed that yesterday  .SOV does not show timestamp now till second level. However nonetheless discussion between you and Chris led me to correct answer.Hence I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try the `Random.NextBytes` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
private byte[] GetByteArray(int sizeInKb)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    byte[] b = new byte[sizeInKb * 1024]; // convert kb to byte
    rnd.NextBytes(b);
    return b;
}
```

**If you need cryptographically safe random bytes, use `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` instead**.

Comment: Are your bytes much bigger than normal bytes? ;-) Seriously though, note the input is a size in *Kb* so you'll want to multiply by 1024 to get an array with the right number of bytes.

Comment: good catch @Chris!  didn't pay attention to the variable name :)

Comment: If you want cryptographically strong random data, use System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(byte[]).  Sorry, I just shut down my dev system, so I can't code up a sample.

Comment: This does not in any way answers question - "Is my array size correct , when user inputs value in kb e.g. 10 KB".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the poster originally asked only "how to fill a byte array with random data". He then copied the code from my proposed solution and asked a new second question.

Comment: @panohh : I did not copied your code and posted , I was responding to grooveplex  about what I had tried already.

Comment: It should be byte[] b = new... rather than Byte[] b.

Comment: Just a side note. Since Random is instantiated within this function, the output of this function will always be the same per a specific size. To make it unexpected, the Random object should be instantiated outside this function.